# How do I share my partition with another local user?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, users

I've made another *Standard User* (user without root privileges) on my Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 system, and I want to share one partition to New user. by default New User doesn't have access to that partition.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  19.1G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0  85.1G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   220G  0 part /media/sumeet/Stuff
├─sdb2   8:18   0   220G  0 part /media/sumeet/Movies
├─sdb3   8:19   0   710G  0 part /media/sumeet/Hollywood
└─sdb4   8:20   0   713G  0 part /media/sumeet/Series
```

I want to share `sdb1` mounted at `/media/sumeet/stuff`

---

This is not about collaborative work. the partition I want to share with new user (my sister) contains data that she needs and might want to save, but I (admin) wants to keep track of that data. that's it. The original situation is posted in this another question which led me to create a new user [Is their a way to *Screen pin* an app in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911849/is-their-a-way-to-screen-pin-an-app-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Do you realize that writing is a superset of deleting?

Comment: @heemayl I just realized that after I sent it ! How about two sub folders, one with read only existing data and the new user only allowed to write in the other folder for new data ?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as long as the new user doesn't have root-privileges and the file in the partition have  proper ownership and permission (files are owned by yourself and have i.g. 755 permissions. But you cant prevent the new user from deleting file he created himself.

Comment: see new user can write in /home (that part of storage is readily available I think) , so if i just want new user to have read access to `sdb1` that should be enough.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Hi, if your question is about collaborative work on a file then please clarify it instead of trying to force an already set system of file permissions.

Comment: @userDepth not really, I've updated the question with actually situation, tell me what should I add more?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit, are you trying to share a folder with another **local** user? If so, the correct way to do this would be with permissions and groups. Create a group, add the user to it, then do a recursive `chown` on the folder in question setting `user:group` and then a `chmod` that says "full rights to user, read only for group, nothing for the rest".

Comment: @pzkpfw yes it's a local user!

Comment: Then you have your answer. If there's something you don't understand let me know and I'll post a proper answer explaining it when I have time, but for now the manual pages for `chmod` and `chown` should be enough, and finding info on how you add a user to a group is also fairly simple. Good luck!

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Are you stuck about trusting the write permissions? IN that case start by keeping  a back up for this files until you see giving this permission is safe with you sister. It's looks like the only practical handling for this situation.

Comment: @userDepth that seems about right.

Comment: I can't say for sure but since you're using Ubuntu, I'm assuming the drives are formatted as ext. If that's the case you're out of luck, otherwise, you might consider setting the `u` attribute to your files. This will not prevent them from being removed but if they are, you can "undelete" them easily. Note that this also does not prevent anyone from zeroing the files since that can write basically anything in the files.

Comment: @Ginnungagap sadly i'm using Ext4

Answer (score 1):

Once you get write permissions on a file comes the ability to delete the file or even leave it blank. So in this situation, we only get to give the additional permission to write to a file in sum to the ability to read it.

Think it as a book you either read it or you can take pages out or put it in the trash can all-together **if it yours** and that's why you are required at a library to return the book meaning you aren't allowed write permissions neither can you delete it from the books database where you borrowing it, was registered. Mainly because the thing is the **owner of the file has all rights to it**.

To do this indicate **Gnome-Disks** to mount as *Read-Only* in the mount options.

Search for "disks" in your launcher open it and look for the disk you need to change the mount options on. Then click the right button before the partition details.

Click "Edit mount options" from that menu
[image]

Switch out of automatic mount options and add ",ro" to the end of the options

[image]

Click OK and provide your **administrator password**, your disk will still be auto-mounted.

Comment: This is helpful information for sure, but I don't think it provides a definitive answer to the question

Comment: The question is about sharing a folder with rw permission without the ability to delete existing data, not how to mount a drive as read only.

Answer (score 0):

What about something as mirror structure? Where hard linked files exist in two separate folder's structures, which have different access permissions:

- The two folders are synchronized, by a script, during a certain time.
- Any file (or folder) can be actually deleted when it is deleted in the both folder's structures. This could be done by a custom command, owned by `admin`.
- Only `admin` has an access to the both folders.
- With right permission, within "its" folder, the `guest` user will be able to read and even to *"delete"* files (and folders) owned by `admin`, but won't be able to modify them. Also the user will be able to create own files and folders everywhere within "its" folder tree.
- The only thing we cannot prevent in this scenario is а save of "blank file", that will erase the content of the file's inode.